# Appropriate times to use cur_data() vs across() in dplyr 1.0

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is a situation where using `cur_data()` and `across()` yields the same result:

```
library(tidyverse)
by_cyl <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl)
a <- summarise(by_cyl,head(cur_data(), 2)) 
b <- summarise(by_cyl,head(across(), 2)))
identical(a,b)
#TRUE
```

My question is what is the difference between these two functions? When are they interchangeable and when are they not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some misunderstanding. `across` and `cur_data()` are not related/interchangeable because they both are for different purpose.

`across` is used to apply a function on multiple columns, `cur_data` returns the current data for a group without the grouping variable.

In the example shared when you are using `across()` it does nothing and returns data as it is.

For example,

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% summarise(across())
```

returns the same `mtcars` dataset as it is because the default values in `across` are `.cols = everything()` and `.fns = NULL`. So it applies `NULL` function to all the columns.

I am not sure what output you were expecting in this case.